# Разные типы для возвращения у функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

Как мне написать типы так, чтобы при вызове функции `domUtils.create('img')` - у меня возвращался тип `HTMLImageElement` ?

```
export const domUtils = {
  toArray<T>(element: T): T[] {
    return [].slice.call(element);
  },
  get(selector: string): HTMLElement {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  },
  create(element: string): HTMLImageElement | HTMLElement {
        if (element === 'img') {
            return document.createElement(element) as HTMLImageElement;
        }
    return document.createElement(element) as HTMLElement;
  }
};

const imageNode = domUtils.create('img');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export const domUtils = {
  create<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
    element: T
  ): HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] {
    return document.createElement(element);
  }
};

const imageNode = domUtils.create('img');
```

> Да, я увидел это в lib.dom.d.ts, не подскажите, как самому такое сделать?

Воспользуйтесь [перегрузкой функции](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), например, так:

```
function create(element: 'img'): HTMLImageElement;
function create(element: string): HTMLElement;
function create(element: string): HTMLElement {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

export const domUtils = {
  create,
};

const imageNode = domUtils.create('img');
const aNode = domUtils.create('a');
```

Comment: @МихаилКамахин дополнил ответ

Comment: Благодарю! ////